# Randomly when opening my fridge it trips other breakers such as dining room

Tags: wiring

At random times when opening my fridge doors it will trip my dining room lights or kitchen lights. Or if both of those are off it will trip my bedroom lights. It’s very frustrating. Local electricians are stumped. Any ideas? The fridge breaker never trips itself. It only trips other breakers. And these breakers are not next to the fridge breaker in the box.

Comment: wow, nasty! .... in breaker panel, swap the fridge breaker with one of the ones that trips .......... on further thought, it may not be random at all. there may be an event that you are missing. things like furnace being on, dining room lights dimmer(if you have one) being set a certain way .... it may not also be the mechanical shock of opening the fridge door that is causing the issue ..... it is possible that the fridge breaker is supposed to trip, but something is preventing it from tripping (mis-wired maybe)

Comment: Yes, odd. And, opening a fridge door does not itself draw any significant current. What kind of bulbs does the fridge use? Also, please plug a hair dryer in the fridge outlet and try it when the compressor is not on. This will A.) Cause noise on the line, an B.) Draw current. Presuming it has no effect, I would look more to the wiring in the walls? Can you "rock" the fridge in place, does it trip breakers? How old is the fridge?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How old is your house? Where are you located? Is this new, and if so when did it start?

Comment: Does the circuit breaker have any buttons on it like "test"?  If you remove the fridge light bulb, does the problem persist?

Comment: What make and model is this fridge, and what make and model is the breaker panel?

Comment: I'm with @Harper. When you say "trip" do you mean its tripping on overcurrent or Arc Fault or Ground Fault?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. House is 2 years old. Breakers do have test on them. Fridge is whirlpool breaker panel is Siemens as are breakers. It’s arc fault that lights up each time. Type QAF2 breakers which I had my original electricians come out 6-7 times during our 1 year warranty. They cleaned off insulation from can lights. Checked wires best they could. Changed the main breakers that would trip each time. Fridge is full of led lights. Not just one bulb.